# DataGridView not displaying values from text file

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView on my form which, when the form loads, is to read from a text file which has the following contents:

```
Alpine Ice Arena:Birmingham Alabama:2000:3200:
Point Mallard Ice Rink:Decatur Alabama:3000:2500:
Florence Coliseum:Florence Alabama:1200:5000:
```

The value of the first field in each line:
**`Apline Ice Arena`, `Point Mallard Ice Rink`, `Florence Coliseum`**
should be displayed in the DataGridView when the Form loads.
However this isn't happening and I can't for the life of me work out why (although there are no errors whatsoever).

The code I have is the following:

```
Public Class frmVenues
    Public Structure VenueInfo
        Public venue_name As String
        Public venue_location As String
        Public venue_capacity As Integer
        Public venue_hirecost As Integer
    End Structure

    'Profile List of Venues
    Public Shared VenueInfos As New List(Of VenueInfo)()   'roster data

    Private Sub frmVenues_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'read all infomations of wrestler from file. lines is profile array
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("venues.txt")

        For Each line In lines
            'Parses the line string, make Venue Info and add it to Venue List
            'split string with ":"
            If line.Trim.Equals("") Then Continue For
            Dim strArr() = line.Split(":")

            'make Venue Info
            Dim vi As New VenueInfo()

            vi.venue_name = strArr(0)
            vi.venue_location = strArr(1)
            vi.venue_capacity = strArr(2)
            vi.venue_hirecost = strArr(3)

            'add Venue Info to Venue List
            VenueInfos.Add(vi)
        Next
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillDataGridView(mode As Integer)
        DataGridView1bnb.Rows.Clear()
        For Each vi In VenueInfos
            Dim row As String() = New String() {vi.venue_name}
            DataGridView1bnb.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you even calling `FillDataGridView`? Try calling this in your load event

Comment: Also, the parameter in `FillDataGridView` is not being used at all, and should be removed as it is redundant.

Comment: I’m an idiot haha thank u I don’t know how I didn’t see these errors.

Comment: Also, instead of using a `For Each` loop in `FillDataGridView`, set the `DataGridVew.DataSource` to your `List(Of VenueInfo)` in the Load event. You can then remove the `FillDataGridView` entirely: it's not needed (unless it's performing some other tasks not shown here).

Comment: *"I don’t know how I didn’t see these errors"*. I do. It was because you didn't debug your code. When things go wrong, the first step is to read the code and see if anything obvious jumps out. If not, the next step is to debug, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through the code, examining the state at critical steps. If you had done that then it would have been obvious that that method was not being called. If you don't know how to debug with breakpoints, stop what you're doing and learn now. It's an essential skill for any developer.

Comment: DataGridView1bnb.DataSource = New List(Of VenueInfo) is this correct? If so it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: **`DataGridView1bnb.DataSource = VenueInfos`**, after you have filled the List content. Btw, the List doesn't need to be static (shared), at least with what you're showing here.

Comment: For some reason when i do this nothing gets shown in the datagridview. It looks as if there are three rows however there is no text in them, they are invisible.

Comment: From what I see here: `vi.venue_capacity = strArr(2)`, you're trying to assign a string to an integer value. That's not possible and should generate an error. There's the chance (possibly having Option Strict Off, you should turn it ON now and forever) that, since you're assigning the properties values in the Load event of the Form, that the exception is swallowed and you end up with empty strings and unassigned value. Set Option Strict ON and move te code to the Shown event of the Form.